# multiple backgrounds with background classes in css

Tags: html, css, class, background

Hi I have just started investing some time in css and html so my question might be too basic for this forum but since i ve been googling quite some time now without finding a fitting answer I wanted to try my luck here.
What I am trying to achieve is multiple pages with each a different background picture .

on the HTML side I use this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title> Page02 </title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">


    </head>


    <body class="one">
            </body>
```

On the css side it should call upon this:

```
body.one {
    background-color: #999;
color:white;
background-image: url("Images/backgrounds/Background02.jpg");
```

}

I have only recently started so I might be going about it the wrong way .
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It would be helpful if you use a jsbin link or some examples of what you're looking for.

Comment: thanks but my problem was my main.css being in a folder (css/main.css) and apparantly the path to my background image cannot be to a folder on the same level or higher then the one that stores my stylesheets. So that brings me to the next problem to solve. Thank you for the fast reply though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your question is essentially, "Is this right?" then my answer is almost.

I would suggest using an id instead of a class on your `<body>` tags. Classes are used only when you're sure you want the exact same styles on two or more elements, while ids are for unique styles on unique elements.

Comment: wouldn't this deprive me off using an "id" further on this page ( for a div for ex.). Should i intent to use the same background on another page (not mentioned in question,just wondering) is using class for body more appropriate?

Comment: True, if you used `id="one"` on your body then you would be discouraged from using the same id on any other element, but at least you would be using ids correctly. If you're using `class="one"` on your body and then applying `body.one {}` styles in your css, you're using a class for a unique element, which is inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are making a mistake in providing the exact path to your image or main.css